# Display slider in magento home page

Tags: php, magento

I am using `magento 1.9.0.1`. And I installed theme `pagayo-theme-003` from [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-theme-jewelry-by-pagayo.html)

This theme already contain slider. But the slider is not showing. The slider code is available in `home.phtml` in `magento\app\design\frontend\default\pagayo-theme-003\template\pagay\home.phtml`.

I don't know why the slider is not displayed.

When I write this slider code in `1column.phtml` the slider is displayed. But this results in all pages. I only need slider in `home page`.

When i write the slider code directly in `CMS->Pages->Home Page-> Contents` gives no results.

So how can i display the slider in Home page. Please help me..
Thanks...

Comment: try this another [magentocommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/banner-slider-magento.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit your CMS Page with identifier 'home', and add in the content :

```
{{block type='core/template' template='pagayo/home.phtml'}}
```

The template (phtml file) will be included in your Homepage, and the Slider will be there too ;)

Hope this helps.

EDIT :

From pagayo website :

> Step 4: Configure Homepage
>
> Go to CMS > Pages > home (select home as URL Key)
>
> Under Content > Content box: Hide Editor and add this code:
>
> {{block type='core/template' template='pagayo/home.phtml'}}
>
> Under Design > Page Layout: Select 1column from the Layout Dropdown
>
> Under Design > Page Layout: Add this code Layout Update XML:
>
> *** 5
>
> Here *** will be any category you want to display on your Homepage.
>   For example:
>
> 10
>
> Click Save Page.

Comment: I'm posting a new answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to configure your home page.

1. Go to CMS -> Pages > home (if home page not exist create one)
2. Click Page Information Tab and put Page title 'home' and page url 'home'
3. Now click Content Tab and click show/hide editor and put this code:

   {{block type='core/template' template='pagayo/home.phtml'}}

4.1 Now Click Design Tab and select layout as 1column from the Layout Dropdown

4.2 Layout Update XML add below code:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>your_cat_id</category_id></action>
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>5</count></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Where your_cat_id is the id of the category from which you want to show products on home page e.g:

```
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>5</category_id></action>
```

Where 5 is your category code

Click Save Page and clear cache.